# PowerShell ISE Crash on Ctrl-Space

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I'm running PowerShell 5.1 on Windows 10.  From within ISE anytime I press ctrl-space to get parameter options I am greeted with this error.  How can this be fixed so it stops crashing?

```
---------------------------
Windows PowerShell ISE - Error
---------------------------
An unexpected error has occurred, and Windows PowerShell ISE must close.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Here is a clip of the error. https://1drv.ms/v/s!AiMOucOyxOOXpv9HNcBhtRB_3EenRQ

This is the Error Message found in my Event Log:

```
Fault bucket 1812796752988013931, type 5
Event Name: PowerShell
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: PowerShell_ISE.exe
P2: 10.0.17133.73
P3: System.NullReferenceException
P4: System.Reflection.TargetInvocation
P5: indows.PowerShell.GuiExe.Internal.GPowerShell.Main
P6: System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod
P7: unknown
P8: 
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERCFC.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERD1C.tmp.xml
WPR_initiated_DiagTrackMiniLogger_One Trace User Logger_20180413 Event Collector_0_inject.etl
\\?\C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Temp\WERD8A.tmp.etl
WPR_initiated_DiagTrackMiniLogger_WPR System Collector_inject.etl
\\?\C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Temp\WERD8B.tmp.etl
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERD88.tmp.csv
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERDA9.tmp.txt

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\Critical_PowerShell_ISE.e_e2745585682c4b8155c7a88cbc449178e619e3d_00000000_11751de4

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: e623efbd-07de-433c-864a-d66b781fec1a
Report Status: 268435456
Hashed bucket: af516355a9c3f706f928590acfd5056b
Cab Guid: 0
```

Comment: Try running `powershell_ise.exe -NoProfile` and see if that helps; maybe you have something being loaded implicitly that's messing with it.

Comment: Yes I tried this but no luck. ISE continues to break as soon as I initiate ctrl-space

Comment: This is now happening in the latest release. Running in the debugger says `Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in WindowsBase.dll
'Assertive' is not a valid value for property 'LiveSetting'.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're on the insider preview. There are two known issues with intellisense, it either causes a fatal error or does not populate (shows a grey dot).

This should be reported via the [Microsoft Feedback hub](https://aka.ms/Ortvxl) - Search "powershell ISE Intellisense not working".

I know this definitely affects builds 17093-17133.

Comment: On build 17666 this is fixed.